# Rewrite all url to another url except one in nginx

Tags: linux, redirect, nginx

I want redirect

```
https://dev.abc.com/ to https://uat.abc.com/

https://dev.abc.com/first to https://uat.abc.com/first

https://dev.abc.com/second to https://uat.abc.com/

https://dev.abc.com/third/ to https://dev.abc.com/third/ (Point the same)
```

I have tried with following config and achieved first three. But last one also redirecting to uat. Can anyone help me in this situation.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dev.abc.com;
        root /var/www/

      location ~* ^/first{
      return 301 https://uat.abc.com$request_uri;
      }

      location ~* ^/second{
      return 301 https://uat.abc.com;
      }

      location ~* ^/{
      return 301 https://uat.abc.com$request_uri;
      }
```

Can anyone help me on this configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`location ~* ^/` matches any URI that begins with `/` - which is **any URI** that hasn't already matched an earlier regular expression location rule.

To match only the URI `/` and nothing else, use the `$` operator:

```
location ~* ^/$ { ... }
```

Or even better, and exact match location block:

```
location = / { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Exact match location block works for me. Thank you [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)